# Joomla - Custom component url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, url-rewriting

I have the following component @

```
?option=com_tmportal&module=user&task=main
```

I've enabled url rewriting and setup the htaccess file which is all working correctly, how would I create a rewrite rule that allows me to access the component above by simply doing:

```
/portal/ = ?option=com_tmportal

or

/portal/user = ?option=com_tmportal&module=user

or

/portal/user/main = ?option=com_tmportal&module=user&task=main
```

Thanks for any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You haven't specified Joomla version so I'm assuming 1.6/7/2.5 in my answer.*

**Short Answer:** If you're using Joomla!'s default .htaccess then all you have to do is create a Joomla! menu to each of your components views with the right alias eg. `portal` for your default component access ie. `?option=com_tmportal`.

This is what the default `.htaccess` does it passes all of the elements after the base URL to `index.php` to help select the component and view.

**Longer Answer**
When you create a component for Joomla! you specify [the menu settings for each view](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_%28MVC%29_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_03) using an XML file usual the same name as the view file in it's `view/tmpl/` directory.

Typically the url to a specific view & task in a component would look like these:

```
?option=com_mycomponent
?option=com_mycomponent&view=userdetails
?option=com_mycomponent&view=userdetails&task=main
```

Joomla!'s framework will automatically use the `view` & `task` params to get your components correct controller and view (or sub-view). I'm not sure that it does anything with the `module` param that you have in your URL's so I'd guess you're trapping and processing that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help, changed module to view and I can now do: /component/tmportal :)